# power bi table total not showing

Tags: powerbi, dax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Selu.png)

```
IMS Rev Accounts counttest = 
VAR CurrentYearRevenue = [IMS Rev Current Year]
VAR PriorYearRevenue = [IMS Rev Prior Year]
VAR Difference = CurrentYearRevenue - PriorYearRevenue
RETURN
IF(
    NOT(ISFILTERED('FACT'[SoldToCustomerCode])),
    SUMX (
        VALUES ('FACT'[SoldToCustomerCode]),
        IF(
            ISBLANK(PriorYearRevenue) && NOT(ISBLANK(CurrentYearRevenue)),
            CurrentYearRevenue - PriorYearRevenue,
            BLANK()
        )
    )
)
```

i have this code that i want to be able to see how much revenue is won.
but for some reason i can see each individual row having the revenue won. but the table total is not showing up. can anyone please help me on this